# Where are the opcode 0xfe and 0xfd documented?

Tags: solidity, yellow-paper, opcode

The Solidity documentation has [the following](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions):

> Internally, Solidity performs a revert operation (instruction `0xfd`)
>   for a require-style exception and executes an invalid operation
>   (instruction `0xfe`) to throw an assert-style exception.

When looking in the [yellow paper](http://gavwood.com/paper.pdf), I cannot see the opcodes `0xfd` and `0xfe` documented. (The largest non-suicide opcode is `0xf4` for `DELEGATECALL`.) Where are `0xfd` and `0xfe` formally documented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably a result of the technology moving faster than updates to the yellow paper.  Your best bet is to go to the source.  Pyethereum is a good source for readability.  You can see the latest [opcodes here](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/blob/develop/ethereum/opcodes.py#L74) (where 0xfd) is referenced.  I would also look [here](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/blob/develop/ethereum/vm.py#L209) for more details and a potential hint into invalid operations.  EIPs such as the one for revert are also a good source of information: [REVERT](https://github.com/ethereum/eips/issues/140)

Comment: Can you confirm that the REVERT opcode will come with metropolis, i.e. that is not yet in production? https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/14726

Comment: Yes REVERT opcode comes with Metropolis : https://themerkle.com/top-3-ethereum-metropolis-changes-to-look-forward-to/

Comment: links does not work. please update the links? thank you